# Wordpress 404 cannot be found error when linking to envato theme via FTP

Tags: wordpress, ftp, themes, http-status-code-404, absolute-path

I am trying to setup a new Wordpress website which I think I have done correctly. However, when uploading a theme via FTP (could not be done via the dashboard) and then link to it inside the dashboard, I keep getting a 404 cannot be found error. Also what concerns me is that when I try to link to it (via FTP) it shows the absolute path on the 404 error page. So confused!

This is the url: http://ldnapprenticeships.co.uk/var/www/vhosts/ldnapprenticeships.co.uk/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/uncode/library/css/

Please forgive me, I have very limited knowledge backend! Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the URL of the page you gave it is actually:
http://ldnapprenticeships.co.uk/wp-content/themes/uncode/library/css/

```
var/www/vhosts/ldnapprenticeships.co.uk/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/uncode/library/css/
```

is the server path.

Comment: Yes.  The style sheet is here and works fine:  http://ldnapprenticeships.co.uk/wp-content/themes/uncode/library/css/style.css

Comment: do you know though why it is giving me a 404 error when I try to connect to the theme (to the purchased theme in envato)? Good to know that it is working fine, thank you!